# Derivative of Scalar Expansion in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, derivative, automatic-differentiation

I'm working on implementing a very simple auto diff library in Rust to expand my knowledge on how it is done. I have most everything working, but when implementing negative log likelihood, I realized that I have some confusion on how to handle the derivative for the following scenario (I've written it in PyTorch below).

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grads=True)
y = x - torch.sum(x)
```

I've looked around, experimented, and am still a little confused on what is actually happening here. I know that the derivative with respect to x of the equation above is [-2, -2, -2], but there are a number of ways to get there, and when I expand the equation to the following:

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grads=True)
y = torch.exp(x - torch.sum(x))
```

I am completely lost and have no idea how it derived the gradients for x.

I'm assuming the above equations are being rewritten to something like this:

```
y = (x - [torch.sum(x), torch.sum(x), torch.sum(x)])
```

but am not sure, and am really struggling to find info on the topic of scalars being expanded to vectors or whatever is actually happening. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

If helpful, I can include the gradients pytorch computes of the above equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work with PyTorch without any modification because it doesn't specify what the gradients w.r.t to `y` are. You need them to call `y.backward()` which computes the gradients w.r.t to `x`. From your all -2 result, I figured the gradients must be all ones.

The "scalar expansion" is called [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html). As you already know, broadcasting is performed whenever two tensor operands have mismatched shapes. My guess is that it is implemented in the same way as any other operation in PyTorch that knows how to compute the gradients w.r.t its inputs given the gradients w.r.t its outputs. A simple example is given below which (a) works with your given test case and (b) allows us to still use PyTorch's autograd to compute the gradients automatically (see also [PyTorch's docs on extending autograd](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-autograd)):

```py
class Broadcast(torch.autograd.Function):
    def forward(ctx, x: torch.Tensor, length: int) -> torch.Tensor:
        assert x.ndim == 0, "input must be a scalar tensor"
        assert length > 0, "length must be greater than zero"
        return x.new_full((length,), x.item())

    def backward(ctx, grad: torch.Tensor) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, None]:
        return grad.sum(), None
```

Now, by setting `broadcast = Broadcast.apply` we can call the broadcasting ourselves instead of letting PyTorch perform it automatically.

```py
x = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
y = x - broadcast(torch.sum(x), x.size(0))
y.backward(torch.ones_like(y))
assert torch.allclose(torch.tensor(-2.), x.grad)
```

Note that I don't know how PyTorch actually implements it. The implementation above is just to illustrate how the broadcasting operation might be written for automatic differentiation to work, which hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for linking your blog post, going through it right now and really liking it! I know the python code above won't work, I omitted some things for brevity that I probably should have not. Thank you for the thorough answer!

Comment: @Silas I didn’t link to my blog posts at all. The links all point to PyTorch’s documentation. Anyway, glad that you find the answer helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a few things, the argument is `requires_grad` and not `require_grads`. Second, you can only require gradients for a floating point or complex dtype.

Now, a scalar addition/multiplication (note that subtraction/division which can be viewed as addition with a -ve number/multiplication with a fraction) simply adds/multiplies the scalar with all elements of the tensor. Hence,

```
x = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
y = x - 1
```

evaluates to:

```
y = tensor([-1.,  0.,  1.], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
```

Thus, in your case, `torch.sum(x)` is basically a scalar quantity that is subtracted from all the elements of the tensor `x`.

If you are more interested on the gradient part, check the pytorch documentation on autograd [[ref](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.backward.html#torch-autograd-backward)]. It states the following:

> The graph is differentiated using the chain rule. If any of tensors are non-scalar (i.e. their data has more than one element) and require gradient, then the Jacobian-vector product would be computed, in this case the function additionally requires specifying grad_tensors. It should be a sequence of matching length, that contains the “vector” in the Jacobian-vector product, usually the gradient of the differentiated function w.r.t. corresponding tensors (`None` is an acceptable value for all tensors that don’t need gradient tensors).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the pytorch code. I didn't copy and paste it from what I wrote, and just eyeballed it. I'm familiar with the reference you linked, the use of the chain rule, and the jacobian. My question is more dealing with the derivative of the above equation. In other words, how does PyTorch manage the gradients of expanding the sum of x into a 1 dimensional tensor.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding the question fully. I think you might want to look into how pytorch implements the automatic differentiation operations for broadcasting.

[Noticed an answer that details this already.]